# thinking_sphinx returns an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a controller with a results of the search, based on thinking-sphinx. Both `find_kind_cd` and `find_category_ids` are sphinx scopes.

`@products.search` return an array. I need something like ActiveRecord::Relation or something like that, because I want to implement some methods to it, like `includes` or `maximum`. How can I implement this methods with array?

```
@products = Product.find_kind_cd(Product.product)

@category = Category.find_by(id: params[:category])
@products = @products.find_category_ids(@category.subtree_ids) if @category

@products = @products.search(params[:query]) if params[:query].present?
# TODO includes - bullet gem

@products = @products.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per] || 12)
```

Comment: Sorry, what is wrong with the code you've posted? does it fail? if so at what point?

Comment: why not use `Model.none` this return AR:relation.?

Comment: Guys, I need results of search returned not as an array, but as Activerecord::Relation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search results cannot be an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, because you're querying against Sphinx, not a database. What you actually get back is not an array, but an instance of `ThinkingSphinx::Search` which behaves very similarly to an array.

However, search calls are lazily evaluated, and `page` and `per` are methods that are available on `ThinkingSphinx::Search`, so you can use those. As for `includes`, you'll need to do the following instead:

```
@products = @products.search(:sql => {:include => :category})
```

There's nothing like `maximum` though. But if you do want an aggregation from the database based on Sphinx search results, this should do the trick:

```
Product.where(id: Product.search_for_ids(params[:query]).to_a).maximum(:cost)
```

Comment: Thanks Pat, your hints help me.

Comment: That's useful. I also wondered about returning an `ActiveRecord::Relation` because then you can apply further filters, check permissions etc. The `Product.where(id: Product.search_for_ids...` works well. The only problem I encountered is that you lose the *order* of the search results. Is there a way to make this work without losing any weight/ordering? (or is this asking for too much?).

Comment: Yoav, if you stored the search ids to a variable, and then used that as a reference to sort the results from the `ActiveRecord::Relation` accordingly, you could keep the original order. It's certainly not elegant though... depends how important it is!